# How timeout option in xdmp:http-post works?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

In XQuery code when I make an `xdmp:http-post` call, I can configure a timeout value in the request options. Say I configure it as 5 seconds, it gives a timeout exception back.

My question here is, will MarkLogic try to complete the calling XQuery module or cancel it? Lot of times this needs to be done from admin console to cancel the query manually.

Comment: Why are you executing a module to execute `xdmp:http-post()` to execute a module? Testing a REST endpoint? It would be easier to import a library module and execute it's method(s) or invoke the main module directly instead of making HTTP calls.

Comment: The queries are in a different cluster, I need the information to complete the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will MarkLogic try to complete the calling XQuery module or cancel it?

The module that you happen to be invoking from the `xdmp:http-post()` does not know that the client has timed out and stopped waiting for a response to be sent. It will continue processing the request and work to generate a response.

If you would like for it to have a shorter timeout closer to the timeout value of the module invoking `xdmp:http-post()`, then you could add [`xdmp:set-request-time-limit()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-request-time-limit) to set an explicit (shorter) timeout for this request.

```
xdmp:set-request-time-limit(6),
for $i in (1 to 1000)
return ( xdmp:log("I'm feeling sleepy..."||$i), xdmp:sleep(1000) )
```

You could even accept a timeout value as a request parameter to the HTTP POST, so that the client could dynamically set the timeout per request.